# NSuncaughtexceptionhandler not catching memorywarning crash

Tags: ios, didreceivememorywarning, nsexception

I am using below shown code to catch the uncaught exceptions in my app. The handler is not called when i get received memory warning crash but for all the other crashes the handler gets called. Please help me.

```
   void InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);
    signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGILL, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGFPE, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGBUS, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SignalHandler);}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "catch" that. In cases of low memory pressure iOS actually kills the app and writes a special report for this. Whenever your app gets killed from the outside, there is no way to get notified by this from within the app process.